# Track attach file in browser using extension

Tags: go, file-upload, browser-extension, event-tracking, data-loss

I'm currently researching for the method of **tracking** event that client user attachs a file in the browser. 
Which means whenever user tries to **upload** a file to place such as: gmail, messenger, facebook, slack, etc; I can **grab the info** of that file and **intercept** if I want.

1. What is the info of attach file?

- Basic metadata information: **File name**, size, file format
- **Content of the file** (if the file is human readable: text, doc)

2. What are the intercept actions?

- **Delay** for a specific amount of time: user cannot send file until this delay time is over
- **Block** attach file:

> Method 1: block uploading file

> Method 2: block sending

3. When will I intercept?

- When file name or file content contains the keywords in my **blacklist**

Briefly, those are my aims. If you're wondering why I'm doing this, what I can only say is I want to **prevent sending private files** to the network through "browser" (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc)

Now, I'm quite lost in the document of developing extension and desperately asking for help.

My questions are:

1. Could I achieve those goals using **browser extension**? And are there any successfully *solutions* or *ideas* that you can recommend?
2. Could I intercept so far in popular browser, i.e: Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc? Or the solution will only works in Chrome!!!

P.S: Other solutions **without** browser extension will also be appreciated. (Especially in *Go*)